# Customizing Sign Signature functionality

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica having an inbuild function to accept signature in mobile and attached to the relevant document. I have tried to find the source code in the Acumatica repository and not able to figure it out. How to customize the base functionality?

Answer (score 0):

This is done in the mobile application section of the customization project.  The following is the example from the T400 Mobile training course on Acumatica Open University.

```
update screen SO301000 {
    update container "OrderSummary" {
        ...
        add recordAction "SignReport" {
            behavior = SignReport
            displayName = "Sign"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Just add the recordAction as shown in the example into the container where you want the signature attached.  It should provide an action in the mobile screen and save the signature images as a file attachment to the record tied to the container when utilized.

Comment: I am looking for the code to customize the action after accepting the signature and  stores into acumatica. I want to add piece of my logic before storing it into file section of the document

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe that is in the Mobile API for which we have no source code.  There are ways to get into that code if you get creative, but I cannot share those details because I believe those methods are contrary to the Acumatica license agreement.    I suspect your best course of action is to open a support case with Acumatica Developer Support.